# Converting serial interface data to integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, pyserial

I'm writing some code to read from a serial interface and return the integer value of the data received.

It seems that i need to remove the `"\r\n"` from it. I tried splitting, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import time
import serial
import string         

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM1',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
counter = 0

while 1:
    x = ser.readline()

    if "t" in x:
        print x
        x = int(x)
        print x
        print "temp"
    elif "h" in x:
        print  "hum "
    elif "g" in x:
        print  "gas "
    else:
        pass

    time.sleep(1)
```

Then I have this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/read.py", line 26, in <module>
    x=int(x)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't0\r\n'
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: you need to remove the letters, the `t` is what cause your problem

Comment: Error is clear - input string cannot be converted to int (since there is "t" in string, how would you convert it to int unambiguously?) You need to do some kind of pre-processing on `t` before attempting to convert it. What kind of processing? I'll let you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
import time
import serial
import string         

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM1',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
counter = 0

while True:
    line = ser.readline().rstrip()
    if not line:
        continue

    resultType = line[0]
    data = int(line[1:])

    if resultType == 't':
        print "Temp: {}".format(data)
    elif resultType == 'h':
        print "Hum: {}".format(data)
    elif resultType == 'g':
        print "Gas: {}".format(data)
    else:
        pass

    time.sleep(1)
```

The first change is to [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) the line we read from the serial interface. This removes any `"\r\n"` characters or whitespace from the end of the string. The second change is to split the line into the "type" letter (`line[0]`), and the data (the rest of the line).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/read.py", line 18, in <module>
    resultType = line[0]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: The exact same error? Can you show me the error message? Is the "type" always a single letter?